# Gold schmidt parameter calculation for perovskite materials

Tags: crystallography, perovskites

Gold schmidt parameter was created in order to see if a perovskite crystal structure would have crystal distortion in feasible range or not. This parameter has been extended to various other forms of perovskite, recently to layered double perovskite[1](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.chemmater.9b04021).

Basically one needs to find the shannon ionic radii of all the elements present in the perovskite material($A_4 M^{2+} M^{3+}_2 X_{12}$)

[image]

then you see if t and $\mu$ lie in the range or not.

I have been trying to calculate this for a few different combinations but I am a bit confused.

How can I be sure what is the coordination number for a given position. I actually tried using VESTA for this. We could see which atom is almost touching to the other atoms in the unit cell. One approach would be to look at the number of bonds that it forms(with whatever atom is the closest) or the other is to take in consideration the size of each ion and then see how many atoms are touching to a particular atom(even then there is some confusion as almost all the atoms has some space in between them and due to which some are bit closer and some a bit farther)

References:

1. [Chemical Diversity in Lead-Free, Layered Double Perovskites: A Combined Experimental and Computational Approach](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.chemmater.9b04021)

Comment: +1 but try to stick to 1 question per post. You can write 4 posts if you want.

Comment: As it's been more than 6 months now, have you made any progress with this? Please update us!